# R Recursive + Lag for previous dependent value

Tags: r, tidyverse, lag

I've been reading a lot about lag or accumulate but still can't figure out how do work on mine.
I've worked out a simplified data of mine like below and also my attempt of workaround of this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

currDt = ymd(20211130)

polyData = structure(list(CCDATE = structure(c(18716, 18715, 18713, 18712, 8895, 18498, 18690, 18689, 18688, 18323), class = "Date"),
                          CRDATE = structure(c(19080, 18898, 18896, 18895, 18895, 18862, 19054, 19053, 19052, 18687), class = "Date"),
                          mREGNO = c("BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD"),
                          SCHDRNUM = c(7711858, 7710223, 7709517, 7709318, 7709172, 7487762, 7686649, 7684567, 7683420, 7374917),
                          MCCDATE = structure(c(18686, 18686, 18685, 18684, 18864, 18467, 18662, 18661, 18660, 18294), class = "Date")),
                     row.names = c(NA, -10L),
                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# sort accordingly for row processing next step
# by REGNO and latest CHDRNUM
polyData = polyData %>%
  arrange(mREGNO, -SCHDRNUM)

n = polyData %>%
  group_by(mREGNO) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(n = max(n))

n = n$n

polyData_backUp = polyData

# get carried backward CCDATE minus 1 month
# first round is temporary create columns for later use
polyData = polyData %>%
  mutate(# temporary Keep for latest tran of every mREGNO
         Keep = case_when(is.na(lag(mREGNO)) ~ 1, # latest tran or data
                          mREGNO != lag(mREGNO) ~ 1, # latest tran of every mREGNo
                          TRUE ~ 0),
         
         # temporary Carried_MCCDATE for latest and second latest tran of every mREGNO
         Carried_MCCDATE = case_when(is.na(lag(mREGNO)) ~ MCCDATE, # latest tran of data
                                     mREGNO != lag(mREGNO) ~ MCCDATE, # latest tran of every mREGNo
                                     lag(Keep) == 1 ~ lag(MCCDATE), # if latest tran is ok then only carry backwards
                                     TRUE ~ currDt)) # temporary as at date

# keep calculate base on the updated info for every rows
for (i in 2:n) {
  polyData = polyData %>%
    mutate(Keep = case_when(is.na(lag(mREGNO)) ~ 1, # latest tran or data
                            mREGNO != lag(mREGNO) ~ 1, # latest tran of every mREGNo
                            CCDATE <= Carried_MCCDATE ~ 1, # previous CCDATE must have at least one month gap
                            TRUE ~ 0),
           
           Carried_MCCDATE = case_when(is.na(lag(mREGNO)) ~ MCCDATE, # latest tran of data
                                       mREGNO != lag(mREGNO) ~ MCCDATE, # latest tran of every mREGNo
                                       lag(Keep) == 1 ~ lag(MCCDATE), # if latest tran is ok then only carry backwards
                                       TRUE ~ lag(Carried_MCCDATE))) # if latest tran is not ok then will carry from carried
}
```

Basically columns from CCDATE to MCCDATE are the original data sorted by mREGNO and SCHDRNUM (Descending); Columns from Carried_MCCDATE to keep are the ideal result I would want.

The criteria is as below and I've worked it out in excel and have try lag in R but it doesn't work. The reason is because I need to take care of recursive formula at Carried_MCCDATE and another depending column together.

For this sample with this small, I manage to do it with a loop but is there anyway I can achieve this by using tidyverse? Because my actual data is a lot bigger.

```
The Carried_MCCDATE formula would be:
1) If first row of different mREGNO then = MCCDATE
2) If not first row and previous row's keep = 1 then = previous row's MCCDATE
3) Else = previous row's Carried_MCCDATE

Excel formula for cell F1 =IF(C2<>C1,E2,IF(G1=1,E1,F1))

The Keep formula would be:
1) If first row of different mREGNO then = 1
2) If CCDATE <= Carried_MCCDATE then = 1
3) Else = 0

Excel formula for cell G1 =IF(C2<>C1,1,IF(A2<=F2,1,0))
```

Please help and thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: i'm so sorry about that.. have added my original data and attempts.. is that better now? do let me know if there's anything not suffice or clear.. please feel free to comment if you find my codes not efficient as i'm still learning.. thanks again for the guidance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input is `polyData_backUp` We can use `accumulate` from purrr.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)    
     
polyData_backUp  %>%
 group_by(mREGNO) %>%
 mutate(carried = as_date(accumulate(2:n(), .init = first(MCCDATE),
  function(carried, i) if (CCDATE[i-1] <= carried) MCCDATE[i-1] else carried))) %>%
 ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   CCDATE     CRDATE     mREGNO SCHDRNUM MCCDATE    carried   
   <date>     <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <date>     <date>    
 1 2021-03-30 2022-03-29 BBB     7711858 2021-02-28 2021-02-28
 2 2021-03-29 2021-09-28 BBB     7710223 2021-02-28 2021-02-28
 3 2021-03-27 2021-09-26 BBB     7709517 2021-02-27 2021-02-28
 4 2021-03-26 2021-09-25 BBB     7709318 2021-02-26 2021-02-28
 5 1994-05-10 2021-09-25 BBB     7709172 2021-08-25 2021-02-28
 6 2020-08-24 2021-08-23 BBB     7487762 2020-07-24 2021-08-25
 7 2021-03-04 2022-03-03 DDD     7686649 2021-02-04 2021-02-04
 8 2021-03-03 2022-03-02 DDD     7684567 2021-02-03 2021-02-04
 9 2021-03-02 2022-03-01 DDD     7683420 2021-02-02 2021-02-04
10 2020-03-02 2021-03-01 DDD     7374917 2020-02-02 2021-02-04
```

Comment: i see.. this definitely solved my problem!! it's time to learn about this accumulate function.. looks quite useful in cases like this.. thanks again~!